# Sklearn: Correct procedure for ElasticNet hyperparameter tuning

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using ElasticNet to obtain a fit of my data. To determine the hyperparameters (l1, alpha), I am using ElasticNetCV. With the obtained hyperparamers, I refit the model to the whole dataset for production use. I am unsure if this is correct in both, the machine learning aspect and - if so - how I do it. The code "works" and presumably does what it should, but I wanted to be certain that it is also correct.
My procedure is:

```
X_tr, X_te, y_tr, y_te = train_test_split(X,y)
optimizer = ElasticNetCV(l1_ratio = [.1,.5,.7,.9,.99,1], n_alphas=400, cv=5, normalize=True)
optimizer.fit(X_tr, y_tr)
best = ElasticNet(alpha=optimizer.alpha_, l1_ratio=optimizer.l1_ratio_, normalize=True)
best.fit(X,y)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why do you think it's not the correct approach?

Comment: There is so many "tutorials" and "explanations" out there which all vary greatly and yet I haven't seen it done this way. To me this makes the most sense, but I wanted to see if other people agree.

Answer (score 3):

I am a beginner on this but I would love to share my approach to ElasticNet hyperparameters tuning. I would suggest to use RandomizedSearchCV instead. Here is part of the current code I am writing now:

```
#-----------------------------------------------
# input: 
#    X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test: datasets
# Returns:
#    R² and RMSE Scores
#-----------------------------------------------

# Standardize data before
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

# define grid
params = dict()

# values for alpha: 100 values between e^-5 and e^5
params['alpha'] =  np.logspace(-5, 5, 100, endpoint=True)

# values for l1_ratio: 100 values between 0 and 1
params['l1_ratio'] = np.arange(0, 1, 0.01)
```

## Warning: you are testing 100 x 100 = 10 000 possible combinations.

```
# Create an instance of the Elastic Net Regressor
regressor = ElasticNet()

# Call the RanddomizedSearch with Cross Validation using the chosen regressor

rs_cv= RandomizedSearchCV(regressor, params, n_iter = 100, scoring=None, cv=5, verbose=0, refit=True)
rs_cv.fit(X_train, Y_train.values.ravel())

# Results
Y_pred = rs_cv.predict(X_test)
R2_score = rs_cv.score(X_test, Y_test)
RMSE_score = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(Y_test, Y_pred))

return R2_score, RMSE_score, rs_cv.best_params_
```

The advantage is that in RandomizedSearchCV the number of iterations can be predetermined in advance. The choices of points to be tested are random but 90% (in some cases) faster than GridSearchCV (that tests all possible combinations).

I am using this same approach for other regressors like RandomForests and GradientBoosting who parameters grids are far more complicated and demand much more computer power to run.

As I said at the beginning I am new to this field, so any constructive comment will be welcomed.

Johnny

Comment: Excellent first answer.